# Plugin Specific: Events Calendar Pro - Tickets with Product Addons

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I’m using the Events Calendar plugin and the Ticketing Addon with WooCommerce, however I need a little bit of guidance on an issue I'm having. Here’s the scenario:

My client runs walking expeditions for schools. They would like their website to do the following:

1. School goes to website, finds the event and books it online.
2. They list their attendees and all needed information (For this I have used Ticket Fieldsets which is awesome btw!)
3. They want to upsell their camping and walking supplies which are delivered on the group’s arrival, but on an attendee-by-attendee basis.
4. The School pays for the tickets, but they want the parents/guardians of the attendee to login to the site and pay for any extra camping supplies if needed.
5. The order the parents make gets linked to this particular event, with the attendees name and what they have ordered.
6. Ideally, for each attendee going to the event, we will generate a separate invoice, payable by the parents of the attendee. If the parent has paid, the product gets added to the information for that particular attendee and upon arrival my client will give the attendees all their ordered products.

I’m super stuck on this one and I am willing to pay to ensure this works for the client.

Does anybody know of any way this is achievable, have you done something similar before? I would greatly appreciate your input.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question (inasmuch as there *is* a question) is far too broad for SO. You might try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com, but they'll still probably require that you present something to start with.

Comment: @isherwood wordpress.stackexchange.com is just for pure Wordpress questions without 3rd party plugins. Now for sure this question is much more than too broad and **StackOverFlow is not a free coding service** :)